# How to configure JavaMelody to Monitor Jdbc Connections in C3p0 DataSource

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, c3p0, java-melody

I'm using Spring configuration file to configure C3P0. To monitor DataSource I configured `net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceFactoryBean` as mentioned in the user guide of javamelody. But my report is showing 0 Active jdbc connections where as my minPoolSize is 10. What did I miss?

In `web.xml` added `monitoring-spring.xml`

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        contextConfigLocation
    </param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:net/bull/javamelody/monitoring-spring.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

In Spring jdbc Configuration file is:

```xml
<bean id="sql2oDatasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="#{dbProps['ops.jdbc.driverClassName']}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="#{dbProps['ops.jdbc.url']}"/>
    <property name="user" value="#{dbProps['ops.jdbc.username']}"/>
    <property name="password" value="#{dbProps['ops.jdbc.password']}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="#{dbProps['ops.c3p0.max_size']}"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="#{dbProps['ops.c3p0.min_size']}"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="#{dbProps['ops.c3p0.max_statements']}"/>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="#{dbProps['ops.c3p0.timeout']}"/>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>
<!-- Configuring the session factory for SQL-2-O -->
<bean id="sql2oSession" class="org.sql2o.Sql2o">
    <constructor-arg ref="wrappedDBDataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg value="PostgreSQL" type="org.sql2o.QuirksMode"/>
</bean>
<bean id="wrappedDBDataSource" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceFactoryBean" primary="true">
    <property name="targetName" value="sql2oDatasource"/>
</bean>
```

I tried to pass `DriverClass` as `net.bull.javamelody.JdbcDriver` in datasource and `driver` as:

```xml
<property name="properties">
    <props>
        <prop key="driver">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

But `postgresql` driver is not getting registered this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks ok according to [documentation](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#7-jdbc). You see db active connection, pool size values on report that also means your config is ok.

In the other hand active db connection count means how many connections from db connection pool is connection operating with db at **that moment**. 0 active connections is good for you(if your application is working properly). It means your db operations are quickly done. It is hard to catch active connection while db operations are fast.

Comment: Number of active jdbc connections graph is showing nothing.Its just empty graph.At least there should be some spikes.Active jdbc connection and pool size isn't same ??.

Comment: Active connections count and pool size are not the same.  I am not sure  why your graph is empty. May be your db activity is too low see. You can simulate a high db activity for a period then check the graph.